# Android XML Layout Inflater, and abstract classes

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, view, abstract-class

### TL;DR; If an Activity extends an Abstract class, that defines a method, then how come that method was not "found"?

I am witnessing a behavior in Android, and I am not able to tell if its the expected result or not.

I have an Activity, with methods, that cannot be found by the `AppCompatViewInflater.onClick` method

I have an Activity, in it, I have Button(s) that have `android:onClick` atribute (the "method(View view)") as defined:

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

In my Example, I have the following classes:

> ParentExampleActivity

```
abstract class ParentExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    abstract void reset(View view);
    abstract void update(View view);
}
```

> ExampleActivity

```
class ExampleActivity extends ParentExampleActivity {
    public void reset(View view) {...}
    public void update(View view) {...}
    public void alter(View view) {...}
}
```

I have the following Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ExampleActivity">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="alter"
                android:text="ALTER"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="update"
                android:text="UPDATE"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="RESET"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But is causing:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method update(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

But, the `alter` method is working as intended...

How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a compatibility feature or flaw

In 3 different devices, I had different behaviors (I only have 3 devices to test SM-T825, T815Y and XT1603)

In the SM-T825 (Marshmallow), I have only `alter` working

In the T815Y (Lollipop), I have everything working...

In the XT1603 (Kitkat), I have only `alter` working

After fidgeting with my code, and making several (untracked) changes, I was able to deploy in all 3 devices, and have the correct behavior.

It appears that invalidating the cache in Android Studio, and restarting was what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the update and reset methods have `public` access modifiers in ExampleActivity class? Because the ParentExampleActivity doesn't have `public` access modifier for these abstract methods. So when android studio implemented these abstract methods in ExampleActivity, it wouldn't have made them public. Ideally you code should look like this:

```
abstract class ParentExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public abstract void reset(View view);
    public abstract void update(View view);
}
class ExampleActivity extends ParentExampleActivity {
    public void reset(View view) {...}
    public void update(View view) {...}
    public void alter(View view) {...}
}
```

Comment: While I can see where you are coming from (abstract methods are at least package-private), the ExampleActivity has the `public void methodName(View view)` signature, also, the Intellij IDE is showing the method in the "visual xml editor". I believe this to be a bug in the AppCompatViewInflater "compatibility" feature